# How to display error message in ruby on rails after using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I made a web application the the first page has email ,password,and confirm password  if I entered without filling them it do not display any messages how can I do it ?

```
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you setup your flash messages?

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: "flash flash-#{name}" %>
<% end %>
```

You should put that somewhere in your application view.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing an object @user:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    ... show the errors the way you want ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```